# Illegal reflective class exception when running Cucumber

Tags: java, cucumber

Whenever I run my project I'm getting a message like this:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields (file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/info/cukes/cucumber-jvm-deps/1.0.5/cucumber-jvm-deps-1.0.5.jar) to field java.util.TreeMap.comparator
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of cucumber.deps.com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to upgrade Cucumber to make it work with the version of Java you are using. It is recommended that you do this one major version at a time. You can find the release notes here:

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/release-notes